# how to stop dobule click on attribute Link of inertiajs

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

This is my code:

```
<Link :href="`/listing/${listing.id}`" method="DELETE" as="button" preserve-state>Delete</Link>
```

when I click very fast an error occurs as image attached [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYAHa.png)

I want to prevent double click